# Registro con API RESTful en java

Tags: java, mysql, webservice, api, restful

Necesito crear una pequeña aplicación con `java` para que permita realizar un registro a los usuarios, tengo que usar un `API RESTful` y me gustaria saber la relación que hay entre el registro que se almacena en una base de datos `MySQL` y la `API RESTful`.

Answer (score 1):

Cada registro que se almacene en la base de datos se puede llamar también "recurso". Para acceder a dicha información se suele desarrollar una interfaz pública o API. Desde ese API (endpoints) se invocarán a los distintos métodos que implementes con tu lógica requerida.

Cuando se solicita un recurso o registro, se debe invocar a uno de esos endpoints, normalmente, a través del protocolo HTTP(s), por ejemplo:

```
GET https://app.domain.es/api/users
```

Esa petición o request se hace para poder recuperar todos los usuarios de una base de datos. Si ahora quisieras recuperar un usuario en concreto, la petición sería esta:

```
GET https://app.domain.es/api/users/123456789
```

donde ahora estarías solicitando un registro único, en particular, el que tiene un identificador igual a "123456789" en tu base de datos. Pero también podrías recuperar, a través de ese API Rest, usuarios con otro criterio de búsqueda, como por ejemplo:

```
GET https://app.domain.es/api/user?name=Jose
```

Resumiendo, no tiene nada que ver Rest con BBDD, ya que API es para acceder a tu backend y la base de datos es tu capa de persistencia de datos.

Si algo no queda claro, deja un comentario.